# Webpack returns status code 2

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack

I am using [this](https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate) react boilerplate, but I don't think the issue is with the boilerplate itself. The boilerplate uses webpack v2.1.0-beta.15. I've haven't touched the webpack configuration files, but they do work. I must have broken something in my source, but have no idea where to even begin debugging.

Upon building my source files using this command:

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config internals/webpack/webpack.prod.babel.js --color -p
```

The command *seems* to work properly - this is the output:

```
[1066] multi main 28 bytes {0} [built]
    + 1347 hidden modules
```

but the process returns status code 2.

What does this mean? I've tried to find what's going wrong, but haven't been able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite a bit of debugging, I've found the problem was that I had linked a local npm package using `npm link`. Apparently, webpack does not like this, and doesn't feel the need to tell you what the problem is, but that is the case.

My solution was unlinking the package in `node_modules`, publishing the package to the npm registry, then installing the package.

I hope this helps anybody the headache using webpack with local packages.